# In JESS, is there an equivalent command to Java's String.contains("x")?

Tags: jess

As the title says. I am writing an expert system in JESS and I need to read an user input to see if it contains "Windows", "Mac", or "Linux".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(bind ?sentence "The quick brown fox")
(bind ?word "quick")
(if (str-index ?word ?sentence)
   then 
   (printout t "contained" crlf)
   else
   (printout t "not contained" crlf))
```

The `regexp` function lets you use Java's java.util.regexp.Pattern patterns for more sophisticated matching.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I needed to know!